# Mapping a JAXB XML POJO to a PostresgresSQL XML type colum

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, postgresql, jaxb

I have a Java POJO which has JAXB annotations and this class is being referenced in a controller which I'm using to try and add the XML (which is posted to an endpoint) into a Postgres DB column, which I believe is of an XML type.

Note that the project is using Java 7, with Springboot.

## **JAXB POJO (Order class)**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Order {

private String customer;

@XmlElement(name = "orderItem")
private OrderItem orderItem = null;

Order() {
    //for JAXB
}

public Order(final String customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public String getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

//    public void addOrderItem(final OrderItem orderItem) {
//      this.orderItems.add(orderItem);
//    }

public void setOrderItem(OrderItem orderItem) {
    this.orderItem = orderItem;
}

public OrderItem getOrderItem() {
    return orderItem;
}

}
```

## **An OrderItem class**

```
public class OrderItem {

  private String sku;

  private Double price;

  public OrderItem(final String sku, final Double price) {
    this.sku = sku;
    this.price = price;
  }

  public String getSku() {
    return sku;
  }

  public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

}
```

## **OrderEntity is the Postgres representation of the database column**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@TypeDefs(value =  {
        @TypeDef(name="xml", typeClass =     com.github.thealchemist.pg_hibernate.XMLType.class)
})
@Entity(name = "t_order")
public class OrderEntity {

public static final String NAME = "t_order";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "customer", nullable = false)
private String customer;

//    @Lob
//    @Column(name = "orderXml", nullable = false)
//    private String orderXml;

@Type(type = "xml")
@Column(name = "order_xml", columnDefinition = "xml")
private Order order;

public OrderEntity(final Order order) {
    this.customer = order.getCustomer();
    this.order = order;
}

public Long getId() {
  return id;
}

public Order getOrder() {
    return order;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCustomer() {
  return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(String customer) {
  this.customer = customer;
}
```

## **A RestController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
OrderRepository orderRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello there !";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/orders", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public OrderEntity create(@RequestBody final Order order) throws JAXBException   {
    StringWriter orderXml = new StringWriter();
    JAXB.marshal(order, orderXml);

    return orderRepository.save(new OrderEntity(order));
}
}
```

## **And an OrderRepository**

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity,Long> {

    }
```

I have an application.properties file with details of my local postgres db which I can start up.

I then am able to compile the above code, however when posting to the endpoint - http:localhost:8080/orders

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/xml" --header "Accept: */*" -d 
<order>
    <customer>Bob Smith</customer>
    <orderItem>
        <sku>SB123</sku>
        <price>99.99</price>
    </orderItem>
</order>
" "localhost:8080/orders"
```

I get the following message

Could not instantiate JAXBContext for class [class com.mands.springboot.jpapostgres.example.persistance.Order]: 1 counts of  IllegalAnnotationExceptions; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions\nClass has two properties of the same name "orderItem" this problem is related to the following location: at public com.mands.springboot.jpapostgres.example.domain.OrderItem com.mands.springboot.jpapostgres.example.persistance.Order.getOrderItem()

Any suggestions welcome - thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try adding @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) to your Order class ?

Comment: Yes I have done that and retried. I also have removed columnDefinition = "xml" from the Order field in OrderEntity and now see this message when trying to post:

status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError","message":"com.mands.springboot.jpapostgres.example.domain.OrderItem.<init>()","path":"/orders"}

Comment: It looks like he's trying to call a constructor without parameters. Can you try to add one in your OrderItem class ? Also, add an @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) to the OrderItem class.

Comment: @DimpreJean-Sébastien Hi, thanks for reviewing! Appreciated!

I have tried as you have suggested, recompiled, and sent through a POST request again to the endpoint (http:localhost:8080/orders), although now, there seems to be a slightly different error which is:

status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.ClassCastException","message":"com.mands.springboot.jpapostgres.example.persistance.Order cannot be cast to java.lang.String","path":"/orders"

Comment: I think this is because in the OrderEntity I defining the following TypeDef:
@TypeDefs(value =  {
        @TypeDef(name="xml", typeClass = com.github.thealchemist.pg_hibernate.XMLType.class)
})

I'm trying to change the typeClass to a customised OrderUserType class in which I cast to an Order and not a string. 

I have put the code up on Github for easier viewing -
https://github.com/jaygehlot/springboot-postgres-xml-poc

The files of interest would be:
src/main/java/com/mands/springboot/jpapostgres/example/domain/OrderEntity.java

OrderItem.java and OrderUserType.java (still WIP)

Comment: I'm not sure i can help further, but if you have a more detailled error, add it to your question so it can be reviewed.

Comment: @JayGehlot You are using `com.github.the-alchemist:hibernate-postgresql` which gives you `com.github.thealchemist.pg_hibernate.XMLType`, [This commit](https://github.com/The-Alchemist/hibernate-postgresql/commit/f912d584f47911dfddff3d0795065c62b8eec9aa) added `XMLType` ([based on](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Hibernate_XML_Type)) and is [not registered](https://github.com/The-Alchemist/hibernate-postgresql/blob/f912d584f47911dfddff3d0795065c62b8eec9aa/src/main/java/com/github/thealchemist/pg_hibernate/spi/TheAlchemistHibernateIntegrator.java#L41) so you probably need to register the type?